# How to unserialize postmeta and use it in wp_query for search filter

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, serialization, deserialization

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 weeks with no success so hopefully someone here can shed some light on this issue. I have 2 types of serialized data that allow my theme to manage the locations of a post.

The first one is for managing all the locations:

```
{&quot;0&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3526&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Alabama&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;31.964736&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-86.682571&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;1&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1929&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Alaska&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;60.945599&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-152.613790&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;2&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1975&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Arizona&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;34.048928&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-111.093731&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4960&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Arkansas&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;35.201050&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-91.831833&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3584&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;California&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;35.857658&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-120.384729&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;5&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2432&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Colorado&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;39.116675&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-105.408532&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;6&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1031&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Connecticut&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;41.615542&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-72.730693&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;7&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4622&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Delaware&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;38.910832&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-75.527670&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;8&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2595&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Florida&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;Florida, USA&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;28.538335&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-81.379236&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;9&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4117&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;32.157435&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-82.907123&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;10&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2974&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Hawaii&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;19.948410&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-155.851947&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;11&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1330&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Idaho&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;44.068202&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-114.742041&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;12&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2786&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Illinois&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;40.633125&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-89.398528&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;13&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;325&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Indiana&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;40.267194&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-86.134902&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;14&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3255&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Iowa&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;41.878003&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-93.097702&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;15&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2805&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Kansas&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;38.506455&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-98.176629&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;16&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3591&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Kentucky&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;37.839333&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-84.270018&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;17&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4766&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Louisiana&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;30.849501&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-92.156011&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;18&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;936&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Maine&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;44.857978&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-69.426243&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;19&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;69&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Maryland&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;38.917652&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-76.602819&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;20&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1529&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Massachusetts&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;42.407211&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-71.382437&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;21&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3802&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Michigan&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;44.314844&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-85.602364&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;22&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1419&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Minnesota&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;46.729553&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-94.685900&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;23&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1281&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Mississippi&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;32.039738&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-89.384795&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;24&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4792&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Missouri&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;37.964253&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-91.831833&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;25&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1290&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Montana&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;46.879682&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-110.362566&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;26&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4643&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Nebraska&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;41.492537&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-99.901813&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;27&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1398&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Nevada&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;38.802610&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-116.419389&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;28&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3875&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;New Hampshire&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;43.433663&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-71.517464&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;29&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3311&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;New Jersey&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;39.868863&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-74.526511&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;30&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3466&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;New Mexico&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;34.519940&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-105.870090&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;31&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2581&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;New York&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;41.129416&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-74.368522&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;32&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2178&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;North Carolina&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;35.759573&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-79.019300&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;33&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2347&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;North Dakota&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;47.551493&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-101.002012&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;34&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1161&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Ohio&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;40.417287&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-82.907123&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;35&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;826&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Oklahoma&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;35.467560&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-97.516428&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;36&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2304&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Oregon&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;43.772409&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-121.180422&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;37&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1768&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Pennsylvania&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;41.203322&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-77.194525&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;38&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4668&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Rhode Island&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;41.580095&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-71.477429&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;39&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4585&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;South Carolina&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;33.836081&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-81.163725&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;40&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3107&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;South Dakota&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;43.969515&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-99.901813&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;41&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1105&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Tennessee&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;35.517491&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-86.580447&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;42&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;597&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Texas&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;31.219974&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-99.286579&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;5&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;43&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2445&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Utah&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;39.320980&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-111.093731&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;44&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3887&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Vermont&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;44.307765&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-72.577841&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;45&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3123&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Virginia&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;37.431573&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-78.656894&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;46&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1538&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Washington&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;47.583155&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-120.970790&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;47&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1455&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;West Virginia&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;38.597626&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-80.454903&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;6&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;48&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3848&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Wisconsin&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;43.784440&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-88.787868&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;49&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1074&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Wyoming&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;43.075968&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-107.290284&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;7&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;50&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1000&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;---------------------&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;51&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;358&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Bahamas&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;25.617568&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-77.862549&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;52&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1407&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Bermuda&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;32.307800&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-64.750500&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;53&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2559&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Puerto Rico&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;18.220833&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-66.590149&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;54&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1302&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;British Virgin Islands&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;18.346193&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;-64.746646&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;55&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3952&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;---------------------&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;56&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1093&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Australia&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;57&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4731&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Canada&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;58&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1467&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;France&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;59&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2603&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Greece&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;60&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;382&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;India&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;61&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1173&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Italy&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;62&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;2309&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Netherlands&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;63&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;3154&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Spain&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;64&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;4201&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;United Kingdom&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;65&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1431&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Other&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;latitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;longitude&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;zoom&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;radius&quot;:&quot;&quot;}}
```

The second one is attached to each post in postmeta which calls it location:
     a:1:{i:0;s:4:"2178";}

So for example this would call the North Carolina.

The problem is that I am trying to create a simple search with each location being a filter options but have no idea where to start. I know how to query the database but not for serialized data like this. Especially having something like a:1:{i:0;s:4:"2178";} reference the first data and spitting out a location, unserialized.

Any help or direct is GREATLY appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP's unseriliaze function.

```
unserialize($value);
```

Comment: yes i understand that and it turns it into an array but i guess what i am asking more is how do i get the 2nd field to reference the first to get the actual text for the state since the 2nd data does not have North Carolina?